# How can i pass a value to an action using redux logic

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-logic

I've got an action that looks like this

```
export const setTokenTimeout = date => ({
type: SET_TOKEN_TIMEOUT,
date
```

And I want to dispatch it inside of some middleware using Redux Logic, which looks like this

```
const requestLogin =
createLogic({
type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
latest: true,

process({ axios, push, action, getState }, dispatch, done ) {
  const { code, user } = action.payload
  const config = configure(progress(LOGIN_REQUEST)(dispatch))
  return axios.post(Api.AUTH_LOGIN, { code, user }, config)
  .then(res => {
    dispatch(handleSuccess(LOGIN_SUCCESS)(res))
    dispatch(push(Route.WELCOME))
    dispatch(setTokenTimeout())
    done()
  }).catch( e => {
    window.alert(e)
    dispatch(handleFailure(LOGIN_FAILURE)(e))
    dispatch(reset('LoginForm'))
    done()
  })

}
```

I want to pass in a date to my action like this

```
const date = new Date()
dispatch(setTokenTimeout(date))
```

But when I try to dispatch my setTokenTimeout function it catches an error that says

```
TypeError: (0 , _token2.default) is not a function
```

How can it not be a function?

If I just do

```
dispatch(setTokenTimeout)
```

it doesn't give me an error, but I need to be able to pass a value into it.

Comment: How are you importing `setTokenTimeout()`?  Are you using a "named import" or a "default import" ?

Comment: import setTokenTimeout from '../actions/token'

Comment: `setTokenTimeout` is not a default export so you want: `import {setTokenTimeout} from '../actions/token'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you have a mismatch between your "named export" and a "default import".  They need to be the same kind.

So, if you have `export const setTokenTimeout`, which is a named export, you need to have `import {setTokenTimeout} from "./actions/token"`, which is a named import.